# MVC 4 - Razor - Pass a variable into a href url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I pass a variable into a url?

What I try is this but this is not working. The url only shows this:

`http://myurltest.com` and not the full path

```
@if(check1 != "d")
{    
    <li>
        <div class="a"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="b"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://myurltest.com/" + @check1 + "/go/5/true">
        <div class="c"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a href='@string.Format("http://myurltest.com/{0}/go/5/true", check1)'>
```

The point is to insert the whole URL into the markup, rather than combining markup and code parts.

Comment: thank you ver much... its working great.. +1 i accept answer your in 5min when i allow to do it..

Comment: Is this missing the closing )

Comment: Is it possible to generate equivalent html using `@Html.ActionLink("Name", "CompleteURL")`? I tried, but the generated link(lets say: `http://website/controllerB/actionmethodB?id=aaaxxx`) is added to the *current url*. The final link generated is - `http://website/controllerA/http:/controllerB/actionmethodB?id=aaaxxx`.

Comment: @barnes, that depends on how exactly you are generating the link. Can you post a separate question for this, as comments are not right place to discuss such things?

Comment: This doesn't work when the website is hosted as an app and you can't get the whole path, you can create it statically as a var, but for maintenance purposes will be a headache going and replacing all the elements of your url, you should consider @Alberto answers on this case

Answer (score 16):

Using String Interpolation in C# 6

```
<a href="@($"http://myurltest.com/{check1}/go/5/true")" >
```

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)

> In computer programming, string interpolation or variable interpolation (also variable substitution or variable expansion) is the process of evaluating a string literal containing one or more placeholders, yielding a result in which the placeholders are replaced with their corresponding values. It is a form of simple template processing.[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) or, in formal terms, a form of Quasi-quotation (or logic substitution interpretation). String interpolation allows for easier and more intuitive string formatting and content-specification compared with string concatenation.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Comment: Plus one for using string interpolation, most updated response

Answer (score 9):

If it points to an action of your website/app then you should use

```
@Url.Action(your parameters)
```

inside your href attribute.

Notice you can also generate the full link with

```
@Html.ActionLink(your parameters)
```

Those are overloaded methods, Intellisense or google will describe all possible alternatives.

Usually, for links to actions of the same website, these methods are better than manipulating the url string like the proposed `"http://myurltest.com/@check1/go/5/true"` because can be used on local machine (where base URL is localhost:someport) and better than `"@check1/go/5/true"` (relative path) because avoids deployment-time URL mismatches.

On the other side, if the link points to external resource then something like the proposed `<a href="http://myurltest.com/@check1/go/5/true">` is fine.

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: I think anyone who signs their helpful answer "Have a nice day, Alberto" deserves at least a few upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

Try this it is working

```
  <a href="http://myurltest.com/@check1/go/5/true">
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/id?" + check1)">click here</a>
```